# Lista de números naturales en orden descendente

Tags: lista, prolog

Tengo un problema en Prolog. Me han mandado un enunciado tal que "Definir un predicado `nums(N,L)` tal que `N` es un número natural y `L` es la lista de números naturales en orden descendente de `N` a 1." para hacer con programacion logica.

¿Alguien seria tan amable de ayudarme?

Yo tengo esto hecho

```
%Predicado principal
nums(N,L) :-
    esUnNumero(N), esUnaLista(L),
rellenarLista(N, L, N).
%Predicados auxiliares
%esUnNumero
esUnNumero(0).
esUnNumero(s(X)) :- esUnNumero(X).
%esUnaLista
esUnaLista([]).
esUnaLista([_|Tail]) :- esUnaLista(Tail).
%rellenarLista
rellenarLista(0,_).
rellenarLista(s(numero),lista) :-
    appendLista(numero,lista), rellenarLista(numero,lista).
```

¿Estaría bien resuelto?
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Con algunas pequeñas modificaciones se puede jecutar en [swi-prolog](/questions/tagged/swi-prolog).

`s(X)` en swi-prolog se representa mediante `succ/2`, donde el primer parámetro es el antecesor y el segundo el sucesor<sup>1</sup>

Eso nos lleva a que el predicado `esUnNumero/1` quede definido así:

```
%esUnNumero/1
esUnNumero(0).
esUnNumero(X) :-
    succ(Y,X)
    ,esUnNumero(Y).
```

el predicado `esUnaLista/1` queda exactamente igual.

para rellenar lista tenías una llamada a un predicado que no incluiste, que obvié mediante una concatenación simple usando el *pipe* (`|`)

```
%rellenarLista/2
rellenarLista(0,[]).
rellenarLista(Numero,Lista) :-
    succ(Prev,Numero)
    , rellenarLista(Prev,Sublista),
    Lista=[Numero|Sublista].
```

El programa completo queda así:

```
%Predicados auxiliares
%esUnNumero/1
esUnNumero(0).
esUnNumero(X) :-
    succ(Y,X)
    ,esUnNumero(Y).
%esUnaLista/1
esUnaLista([]).
esUnaLista([_|Tail]) :-
    esUnaLista(Tail).

%rellenarLista/2
rellenarLista(0,[]).
rellenarLista(Numero,Lista) :-
    succ(Prev,Numero)
    , rellenarLista(Prev,Sublista),
    Lista=[Numero|Sublista].

%Predicado principal
nums(N,L) :-
    esUnNumero(N)
    , esUnaLista(L)
    , rellenarLista(N, L),!.
```

Como verás en `nums` le puse un corte para evitar que intente infinitas falacias pues solamente hay una solución válida a tu ejercicio.

<sup>1</sup>
Si usas otra implementación de prolog puedes averiguar como es el predicado particular [acá](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197088/what-does-the-s-predicate-do-in-prolog/8197650).